# A confusion about cv-decomposition

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to such rules:
[cv-decomposition](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#def:cv-decomposition)

> A cv-decomposition of a type T is **a sequence of CVi and Pi** such that T is
>
> > "CV(0) P(0) CV(1) P(1) ... CV(n-1) P(n-1) CV(n) U " for n ≥ 0

The example in the such rule is:

> Example: The type denoted by the type-id `const int **` has three cv-decompositions, taking U as “int”, as “pointer to const int”, and as “pointer to pointer to const int”.

According to the above form, I'm able to understand `U` is `int` and CV(n) denotes the `const`, however I can't understand why It also says `pointer to const int` may denote `U`, `pointer to pointer to const int` may denotes `U`, My understanding about the above form is that `U` always denotes the unqualified-cv underlying type.

#### My question:

1. why the example says `U` may denote `pointer to const int` or `pointer to pointer to const int`, Isn't `U` shall denote the unqualified-cv underlying type?
2. It says `A cv-decomposition is a sequence of CVi and Pi` , why `const int **` has three `cv-decompositions`? According to the above form , there are two `Pi`, namely `P(0)` and `P(1)`, they are respectively the last `*` and the second last `*`, and the corresponding `CV(i)` is empty. So I think for type `const int **`, there are two `cv-decompositions`, why `three`?

Answer (score 3):

`U` denotes the original type with zero or more outermost "pointer to" removed together with their *adjacent* "const". There are three ways to do do that with `const int **`.

- U is pointer to pointer to const int (nothing removed)
- U is pointer to const int (one "pointer to" removed)
- U is int (two "pointer to" removed together with a "const" that follows them)

Thus there are three decompositions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218619/discussion-on-answer-by-n-pronouns-m-a-confusion-about-cv-decomposition).